# Delete rows which has a specific value from DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForm DataGridView as follows where I need to delete rows which having a specific value in a column

[image]

In this case I'm using a textfield to type Code and after clicking "Delete" all the rows which having **ITM-000001** under column value. I have no clue where to start.

```
private void deleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    String code = txtCode.Text;
    // CODE HERE       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long while since I did anything with Windows Forms (oh, the good ol' days), so excuse me if this is a little off, but you should be able to accomplish this with something like...

```
for(int v = 0; v < dataGrid1.Rows.Count; v++)
{
    if(string.Equals(dataGrid1[0, v].Value as string, "ITM-000001"))
    {
        dataGrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(v);
        v--; // this just got messy. But you see my point.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily better or even simpler than Matthew's solution; just a different approach I sometimes find useful:

```
    List<DataGridViewRow> RowsToDelete = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        if ( row.Cells[0].Value != null && 
             row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "TTTT") RowsToDelete.Add(row);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in RowsToDelete) dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    RowsToDelete.Clear();
```

This way you could use the list as a buffer after or give the number of hits before actually deleting them.

I also liked his use of `string.Equals`  and do it differently here just for fun..

Comment: Thanks for the effort @TaW